# Incorrectly informed of gaining a privilege

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, rep-requirement

I received the message, "Congrats, you've gained the the privilege - vote up - learn more," in the third link in the top left of Stack Overflow (the bar-chart-like symbol). But when I went to up-vote an answer, I was informed that I didn't have the required 15 rep. When I looked at my reputation, I indeed only have 13 rep, and so fall short of the 15 required for up-voting. Why then was I sent a message saying I had gained that privilege?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer on "[my classes cant reach the first variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159191/my-classes-cant-reach-the-first-variable/22159350#22159350)" was accepted, then unaccepted. The first action triggered the message, and the second removed the privilege.

We don't "revoke" privilege gain messages by design.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check your recent reputation changes, it is possible that you had the correct amount of reputation but some action caused some of it to be revoked (a down vote on a particular answer of yours is a possibility)

Comment: I checked myself, but didn't see any such activity. I assume I'd be able to, even though I'm not the OP...?

Comment: Or the opposite: an upvote which was then reversed. That wouldn't show any record

Comment: That's true @mhlester

Comment: In my list of achievements (in the bar chart like drop down), I can see all the actions that have gained me reputation and they only add up to 13. Would reversing an up-vote remove it from that list too?

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact, it would (but you might want to check with @mhlester, he's more experienced :) )

Comment: On the contrary, I believe you'd see an extra "unupvote" entry. That might depend on whether the vote has locked in (they're on a timer) yet though. If you get "unupvoted" after editing something (which unlocks vote changes), maybe that's the only circumstance in which it logs the unupvote?

Comment: Pretty sure if it was removed in the grace period all trace of it is gone. It makes sense the notification of privilege wouldn't leave though, as this would be such a rare condition

Comment: Ok, so is the consensus that this is working as designed and that the only bug (notification of privilege gained) which was valid when issued, is not removed, is such a rare condition that it is not worth changing anything.

Comment: The opposite doesn't seem to be true. I had an answer down voted, I commented on it and asked why it had been down voted and the vote count has now gone back to 0 on the answer. An up vote was not registered but going back to zero I assume means the down vote was revoked but the reputation -2 still seems to be in effect.